# Apple Xcode4 ITune Connect App Submission

Tags: ios, xcode4

I am trying to submit a revision to my App in the App store. The original App was submitted via XCode3.2 and I am currently on Xcode4. My archived app passes the validation when I use the Organizer validate step however it fails the submission consistently with a strange error. 
The error screen is as follow:

The following issues were found during validation:
!35
!com.apple.transporter.util.StreamUtil.readBytes(Ljava/io/InputStream;)[B

At first I thought may be App Store is experiencing some service interruption but I the error is consistently happening over the past few days so I think something else is wrong but I just dont know what? I have asked apple but they take forever and never answer your question properly. Has anyone else seen this before. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm hitting this problem myself with my first ever app submission, after much searching on google the only real answer I could come up with is reinstall XCode; that didn't seem to help. Might have to send a message to the iTunes connect folks.

Answer (score 0):

Uploading it from a different computer on a different internet connection worked for me. Might have been the transparent proxy used on the first connection, I'm not really sure.

Comment: Thank you for the response. It ended up being the Application loader, downloaded version 1.3 and the app submission went through no problem.